# Only transition between classes A and B, and A and C, but not B and C

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

### A Little Background...

Consider the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item above"></div>
    <div class="item active"></div>
    <div class="item below"></div>
    <div class="item below"></div>
    <div class="item below"></div>
</div>
```

In order to avoid the use of JS, I have used a combination of the following classes to define the state of the items; `above`, `active`, `below`.

- `above` - scales the `.item` down and behind
- `active` - transitions the `.item` from either `above` or `below`
- `below` - places the `item` below the fold

In CSS, this looks like:

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.item {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: transform .8s ease;
    will-change: auto;
}

item.above {
    transform: scale(.8);
}

.item.below {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

### The Problem

Using JS, based on the `active` index, I am simply updating the classes to reflect all items above `.item.active` to have a class of `above` and all below to have a class of `below`...

This works perfectly when navigating by **1** item e.g. 1 -> 2, 4 -> 3 etc. However, when the active index changes by more than **1** (e.g. 1 -> 3, 4 -> 1 etc), the transition is very glitchy because behind the scenes each of the `.above` items are transitioning to `.below` or vice versa.

### My  Question

Is it possible to only apply transitions in the following scenarios:

- `.active` to `.above` - transition
- `.active` to `.below` - transition
- `.above` to `.active` - transition
- `.below` to `.active` - transition
- `.above` to `.below` - do NOT transition
- `.below` to `.above` - do NOT transition

### What I have tried

I knew this wouldn't work, but I tried the following:

```
.item {
    /* Other styles... */
    /*transition: transform .8s ease;*/
}

item.active {
    /* Moved the transition here */
    transition: transform .8s ease;
}
```

This resulted in:

- `.active` to `.above` - NOT transitioning
- `.active` to `.below` - NOT transitioning
- `.above` to `.active` - transition
- `.below` to `.active` - transition
- `.above` to `.below` - do NOT transition
- `.below` to `.above` - do NOT transition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this by adding an extra class, say maybe `.transition`, which has the `transition` property set. Only add this class, if you want the transition, otherwise remove it.